# How can I change amount of payment-plan in flutterwave payment gateway?

Tags: node-modules, payment-gateway, flutterwave

Recently, I developing a project with flutterwave as a payment gateway.
But I couldn't change the amount of payment plan.
So, I investigated Node module.
It seemed like impossible.
I hope experts will help me about this.
Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKxSd.png)

If you have experience in this field, I will be appreciate if you attach some example code.